# jQuery not using selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am building a custom WordPress plugin that requires me to build into it a custom media library button that lets a user associate an image with a certain option for a post. The user needs to be able to add the elements dynamically, so there are multiple options, i.e. multiple medial library buttons.

The issue that I am running into is that if I have 5 options with five buttons, setting the first image works fine. But if I click buttons 2-5 to set the images for the additional options, they are not getting set but the first option is changing.

It's almost like once the initial element is set on click, then it never changes.

Here is a sample of the HTML (the generic.jpg is the default image before the image is set from the library):

```
<div class="image-preview-wrapper">
    <img class="image-preview" src="https://WEBSITE/wp-content/plugins/atas_spec_writer/admin/assets/generic.jpg" style="max-height: 100px; width: 100px;" width="100" height="100">
    <input type="button" class="button upload_image_button" value="Add Image">
    <input type="hidden" name="options[section_4][3][img_id]" class="image_attachment_id" value="">
</div>
```

Here is the JS code:

```js
// Uploading files
var j = jQuery;
var file_frame;
j(document).on('click', '.upload_image_button', function(event) {
      var el = j(this);
      event.preventDefault();
      // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
      if (file_frame) {
        // Open frame
        file_frame.open();
        return;
      }
      // Create the media frame.
      file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Select a image to upload',
        button: {
          text: 'Use this image',
        },
        multiple: false // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
      });
      // When an image is selected, run a callback.
      file_frame.on('select', function() {
        // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
        attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

        el.siblings('.image-preview').attr('src', attachment.url);
        el.siblings('.image_attachment_id').val(attachment.id);
      });
      // Finally, open the modal
      file_frame.open();

      // Restore the main ID when the add media button is pressed
      j('a.add_media').on('click', function() {
        wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
      });
```

I've switched up using j(this), event.target, and they both seem to stick with the first element clicked.

I originally thought that it might just go to the first element in the DOM that matches what is clicked, but if I add 2 options with images and then come back two days later and add two more, the click event sticks with the first element that was set that day, not the first element in the DOM.

So I am completely at a loss......

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like once you open a frame file_frame variable will never be nullified or resetted.

I guess problem lies in the following return statement:

```
   if (file_frame) {
    // Open frame
    file_frame.open();
    return;
  }
```